# Can't run JRE installer on windows 7 or windows server 2008

Tags: java

I download the JRE installer but can't find the exe to run. Please see the screen shot[image]
[image]
Am I missing some other programs here?

Comment: try to extract first.it should be exe file

Comment: Tried. Same problem.

Comment: The `.tar.gz` has nothing _to_ run. It is designed for **manual** installation. You need the `exe` if you do not know how to do that.

Comment: @HualiZ extract it to a folder .what is the extension of extracted file??

Comment: Where did you get that archive?

Comment: I got it from Oracle JRE downloading page. Boris the Spider is right.

Answer (score 0):

The tar.gz file that you downloaded needs to be unzipped TWICE.  I use 7-zip so I don't know all the details of tar and gz. I just tell 7-zip to unzip files.  Unzip the tar.gz produces a file that you can unzip.
Once you do that you should see a folder which contains all the files necessary to run Java.

If you want an exe file.  Go back to the download page and download the .exe.
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jre8-downloads-2133155.html